# Symfony2 get Unmapped field value in symfony forms

Tags: php, mysql, forms, symfony

working on a symfony2 real estate project, and i need to figure out how to store submited data form a dynamically created form in the database.

Here is the work that i have done so far, i have a realestate property `addListings` form with a set of predefined fields, to this i embed a set of additional fields from `options` inside it. these 'additional fields' are decided dynamically by the admin, he can add x number of fields, and he can choose between drop downs or checkboxes or text types.

here is the options and categories form type, its all good, no worries there, just your regular form values submitting to the database

```
/**
 * Inside OptionsType.php
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('value')
        ->add('submit', 'submit', ['label'=>'Create Option'])
    ;
}

/**
 * Inside CategoriesType.php
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('required')
        ->add('isMultiple')
        ->add('isText')
        ->add('submit', 'submit',['label'=>'Create Category'])
    ;
}
```

here is the entity that represents the additional fields `PropertyCategory.php` it has getters and setters no worries here

```
<?php
 namespace path\to\Entity;

 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="property_category")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class PropertyCategory {

/**
 * @var type integer
 * 
 * @ORM\ID
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="University", inversedBy="propertyCategory")
 */
protected $university;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Property", inversedBy="propertyCategory")
 */
protected $property;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="propertyCategory")
 */
protected $category;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Options", inversedBy="propertyCategory")
 */
protected $options;
```

Now here is the real stuff,in the PropertyCategoryType, the Options object is passed as an array to this form, the key of the array becomes the label and the value becomes the options of the form fields, ignore most of it and just look at this line

`$builder->add($value->getCategory()->getName(), $type, $options);`

this is what will create a `mapped=>false` field.
now if you look at the controller `AdditionalDetailsController` below, i have an action named `propertyCategoryFormAction` this is where i insert the user selected data to the database

**So question is how do i get the unmapped field names dynamically like `$form['fieldName']->getData()` so that i can use it to query the database and get the options_id and persist it to the propertyCategory table**

```
namespace path\to\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class PropertyCategoryType extends AbstractType {

public function __construct($options) {
    $this->options = $options;
}

/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    foreach ($this->options as $key => $value) {
        if($value->getCategory()->getIsMultiple()){
            $checkbox[$value->getCategory()->getName()][] = $value->getValue();
            $type = 'choice';
            $options = array('choices'=>$checkbox[$value->getCategory()->getName()],'multiple'=>true, "mapped"=>false, 'expanded'  => true, 'required'=>$value->getCategory()->getRequired());


        }elseif($value->getCategory()->getIsText()){
            $type = 'text';
            $options = array( "mapped"=>false, 'required'=>$value->getCategory()->getRequired());


        }elseif($value->getCategory()->getIsText() == false && $value->getCategory()->getIsMultiple() == false){
            $ddl[$value->getCategory()->getName()][] = $value->getValue();
            $type = 'choice';
            $options = array('choices'=>$ddl[$value->getCategory()->getName()],'multiple'=>false, "mapped"=>false, 'required'=>$value->getCategory()->getRequired()); 

        }

        $builder
            ->add($value->getCategory()->getName(), $type, $options);
    }
        $builder
            ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label'=>'submit', 'attr'=>array('class'=>'btn btn-danger')));
  }


  /**
   * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
   */
   public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
   {
      $resolver->setDefaults(array(
          'data_class' => path\to\PropertyCategory'
      ));
   }


  /**
   * @return string
   */
  public function getName()
  {
    return 'eduflats_bundle_eduflatsbundle_propertycategory';
  }
}
```

Here is the controller `AdditionalDetailsController.php`

```
class AdditionalDetailsController extends Controller
{
   /**
    * @Route("/AddCategory", name="addCategory")
    * @Template()
    */
 public function addCategoryAction(Request $request) {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $category = new Category();
    $form = $this->createForm(new CategoryType(), $category);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid()){
        $em->persist($category);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('addOption', array('id'=>$category->getId())));
    }
    return array('form'=>$form->createView());
}

/**
 * @Route("/AddOption/{id}", name="addOption")
 * @Template()
 */
public function addOptionAction(Request $request, $id){

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $options = new Options();
    $form = $this->createForm(new OptionsType(), $options);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid()){
        $category = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('EduflatsBundle:Category')->findOneById($id);
        $university = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('EduflatsBundle:University')->findOneById(siteConfig::$university_id);
        $options->setCategory($category);
        $options->setUniversity($university);
        $em->persist($options);
        $em->flush();

        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->set('success', 'Your options have been saved Successfully');
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('addOption',array('id'=>$id)));
    }
    return array('form'=>$form->createView());

}

/**
 * @Route("/form", name="form")
 * @Template()
 */
public function propertyCategoryFormAction(Request $request) {

    $options = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('EduflatsBundle:Options')->findAll();

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $propertyCategory = new PropertyCategory();
    $form = $this->createForm(new PropertyCategoryType($options), $propertyCategory);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid()){
        $property = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('EduflatsBundle:Property')->findOneById(1);
        $propertyCategory = new PropertyCategory();

        $propertyCategory->setProperty($property);
        $propertyCategory->setOptions();

        $em->persist($propertyCategory);
        $em->flush();
    }
    return array('form'=>$form->createView());
}
}
```

i hope i was clear enough, i can clarify stuff in the comments.

Comment: I have a similar problem. Care to look into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my thought.  I actually had a job that wanted to do a similar thing, but we ended up abandoning it at the time because this is a difficult thing to manage.  But here's what I planned.

Start with a master entity

```
class Listing
{
    protected $name;
    protected $price;

    //Your custom options (One-to-Many)
    protected $options;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->options = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // Getters and Setters ...
}
```

We then have two entities responsible for handling the custom options.  The option itself which relates to the listing.

```
class Option
{
    protected $name;
    protected $fieldType;
    protected $required;
    // Other form options you may want...

    //Related Values (One-to-many)
    protected $optionValues;

    // Many-to-one
    protected $listings;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->optionValues = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // Getters and Setters ...
}
```

And the value of that option that get's stored in the database.

```
class OptionValues
{
    protected $value;


    // Many-to-one
    protected $option;
}
```

We then build are From for the listing.

```
class ListingType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name' , 'text')
            ->add('price', 'text');
            //Your other standard fields...
            foreach($options['extraFields'] as $field)
            {
                $builder->add($field->getName() , new OptionValueType(), array('mapped' => false, 'options' => array('field' => $field));
            }
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setRequired('extraFields');

        $resolver->addAllowedTypes(array(
            'extraFields' => '\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection'
        ));

        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Listing',
            'cascade_validation' => true
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'listing';
    }
}
```

We require that you pass the `$option['extraFields']` which should be the collection of `AppBundle\Entity\Option` you got from `$yourListing->getOptions()` in your controller.  We then can loop through those and make a new unmapped field, passing the rest of that field to the form for our `AppBundle\Entity\OptionValue` like so.

```
class OptionValueType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        //Obviously do whatever other settings you need.  The important part is remembering that this belongs in the $value
        //of our OptionValue entity.
        $builder->add('value' , $field->fieldType, array('required' => $field->getIsRequired()));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setRequired('field');

        $resolver->addAllowedTypes(array(
            'field' => '\AppBundle\Entity\Option'
        ));

        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\OptionValue',
            'cascade_validation' => true
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Some important things to note.  In both forms we're using `$resolver->setRequired()` and `$resolver->setAddAllowedTypes()` to define our extra option fields or else Symfony will throw errors.  Also, in the Listing form we set `'cascade_validation' => true` to make sure that our sub forms get validated as well, if that's what you want.  You may also need to do some crazy custom validation, that's a whole other bag of tricks.

What this ultimately allows use to do in our controller is limit the amount of crazy custom form manipulation and instead, if you setup your persisting correctly to cascade in both your Listing and Option entities, you should be able to just persist the Listing and it will make sure all the Option and OptionValue entities get persisted to the database as well.  As long as you did everything right.  There's a lot of details I left out because it's a lot to write,  but hopefully this gives you some ideas.

Comment: I've gotta fix a server issue at work :P  I'll try to expand this answer when I can if you need more detail.  I kinda would like to see if this works myself so I can use it in future projects.

Comment: @mojo I'm going to try and build a mini project, and I'll post the link here when done.  May take a day or two as I'll only get to work on it between life.  Or if my answer already got you thinking and you were able to develop something, just let me know.  Otherwise, look forward to a complete example in a day or so.  Cheers.

Comment: hey i was able to do this, i have done it in a slightly different way, it would be great if i could have your version of the answer too, i will post a link to my github project later on today.

Comment: @mojo OK, sorry I haven't responded lately, been super busy at work.  I'm glad to hear you got something working.  Idk if I'll get a chance to get an example going, unless someone suddenly invents a cloning machine. Haha

Comment: i understand, i will post my project link here, so anyone can use it, maybe if i'm lucky they will contribute to my git repository.